# Can someone explain this code for me?

Tags: jquery

Hi im using this code for a list of links that have an animation on their padding. I wanted when i clicked on it to keep that padding and not animate back to its original position. What i dont understand are two things.  "`if (!$(this)`" that part of code and how when i dont have a class of current on any link does it find any? Thanks so much!

```
$(function() {
    $('#secondary_content_what_we_do li a').hover(function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass("current")) {
            $(this).stop().animate({
                "paddingLeft": "10px"
            }, 400).addClass('column_hover');
        }
    }, function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass("current")) {
            $(this).stop().animate({
                "paddingLeft": "0px"
            }, 'slow').removeClass('column_hover');
        }
    });

    $('#secondary_content_what_we_do a').click(function() {
        $('a').removeClass('column_active').removeClass("current");
        $(this).addClass('column_active').addClass("current");
        $('#secondary_content_what_we_do li a').trigger('mouseleave');
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#loading_content').hide().load(url).fadeIn(1000);
        return false;
    });
})
```

UPDATE
For some reason i cant comment. I understand now, but i dont have a class current in my css so i dont know how that line helps.

Comment: the `current` class is added to the `anchor` when it is clicked on: `$(this).addClass('column_active').addClass("current");`. It doesn't matter if you haven't declared any css rules for the class, jQuery is just using it to identify and track the state of elements. So when you hover over an element, the code identifies if the hovered element is the last element which you clicked or not and acts accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement:

```
if (!$(this).hasClass("current"))
```

Is doing several things.  It's wrapping the `this` variable (which in this case refers to the element that was hovered over) in a jQuery object (using `$(...)`), and then calling the `hasClass(...)` method on it, and then notting (`!`) the result.  The statement reads "***If the element that was hovered over does not have the class "current" then execute the code within the block***"

As for the second part of your question, I think you're referring to this line:

```
$('a').removeClass('column_active').removeClass("current");
```

And how it works if the anchor selected doesn't have a class of `current`.  If the `a` element selected has no `current` class, the statement will have no effect (Please let me know if this isn't what you're asking).

Answer (score 2):

The `if (!$(this)` is not a complete expression; the `!` is negating, for example, `$(this).hasClass("current")`.  It would work the same, and maybe be clearer to you, if you wrote `!($(this).hasClass("current"))`.  That expression means "if this object does not have the class 'current'".

The class "current" is getting added to things by the line

```
$(this).addClass('column_active').addClass("current");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#secondary_content_what_we_do li a')
```

selects ALL `a` elements which are descendants of an `li` which is itself a descendent of the element with id `secondary_content_what_we_do`. So this selector returns an *array* of jQuery wrapped DOM elements.

The `this` keyword inside the function refers to the *single* DOM element which triggered the event (`click`, `hover` or whatever).

`$(this)` simply wraps the native DOM `this` element as a jQuery object again so we can access the jQuery functions like `addClass` and `removeClass`

so...

```
$('#secondary_content_what_we_do li a').hover(function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass("current")) {
            doSomething();
        }
}
```

essentialy is saying when we hover over any element matched by the selector, if the specific element we hovered over *doesn't* have the class `current` (the `!` operator reverses the result of the `hasClass` call), then do something.

Answer (score 0):

HTML DOM elements can have more than one class at the same time.  Does that clear thing up?